# Directshow player and windowless activex

Tags: directshow

I am trying to implement a directshow based video player as a windowless activex. The plan is to use the player and have it overlaid by html elements.

The problem I am facing is that for the windowless activex to display video properly, the video needs to be painted to a memory DC provided by the container(ie Internet Explorer). 
I am trying to write a custom allocator presenter but have not made much progress..

Any pointers on how best this can be achieved?

Comment: You output either to clipped window or to DirectDraw/Direct3D surface. To paint onto `HDC` instead you would rather use custom renderer (`SampVid` sample on old SDKs) or 24-bit RGB `Sample Grabber` + `Null Renderer`. Perhaps the easiest would still be to switch to windowed control, if possible.

Comment: @Roman R. I did try the sampvid route...but then bitmap overlays would require another custom filter which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: When you paint over `HDC` you can use off-screen helper `HDC` to overlay all you have before blitting it onto resulting context. This is easier than anything else, but does not use any hardware caps like YUV surfaces etc. (that is not so good in terms of performance, but might be OK for you).

Comment: Thanks Roman. I think that is something that I should try out.